# Youtube video Id Combinatorics

Tags: math

I'm trying to figure out how many possible combinations there are with youtube's current 11 character length video id which takes both lower and upper case alphabet characters (26 + 26) + numbers as well (0-9 = +10).  Is this simply (26+26+10)^11 = 62^11 = 5.2036561e+19.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: This would be a better fit for Mathematics...

Comment: Based on the information you provide then 62^11 would get my vote.

Comment: I want to write "Yes" as an answer, but stackoverflow won't let me because it's too short :-(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se], not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were no other restrictions then yes, you'd have done your math correctly.

However, from what I can gather, _ and - are also possible characters. I don't know if they are restricted from appearing at the start and end. Google has also [not committed to a standard length of 11](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/oAztQ3f1tcM).

If we suppose that a video id can't start with _ or - then you have:

```
62*(64^10)
```

possibilities. You seem to be good enough at this to figure out what it would be if the restrictions were different. Hope this helped.